# Is the hole for the stopper rod in a vanity faucet normally sealed against water?

Tags: faucet

I have a small washroom sink.  Sometimes, when washing my face or hair, or using a Water Pik, water gets on top of the neck/spout of the faucet.  The water trickles down the spout and falls into the hole for the stopper rod and drips to the cabinet underneath.

Is the hole normally sealed against such leakage?

Here is a photo of the problematic faucet:

[image]

Here is a top-down view of the hole for the stopper rod:

[image]

**2024-01-14 update:** Hooray!  After years of babysitting a bin to catch the water below, I asked the superintendent to replace the faucet.  Funny that the alternative faucet was exactly like the one before the current problematic faucet.  It has a very rounded neck, so water dribbles off to the side rather than down the neck to the hole for the plunger rod:

[image]

It's has a shorter neck, so not great in that respect, but that's preferable leaking water down below.

Comment: Should be a sealing washer there somewhere.  If not new, it is possible that it is not sealing well now(worn out).

Comment: OK, thanks.  It might have been like that all the time.  If so, then the washer may have been left out when it was originally installed new, several years ago.  Did you want to post your comment as the answer?

Comment: You're claiming that water is trickling **up** onto the top surface of the faucet where the rod hole is? More likely it's a poor seal around the base of the faucet (where there should be a gasket or caulking) I have never seen a seal around that hole for the rod, because water does not run uphill.

Comment: I am just guessing really.  If I designed it I would use a washer to seal it.  The real designers might have thought it was not necessary.

Comment: @Ecnerwal's comment does make more sense and usually easier to fix.  Would check to sure how the water goes, I assumed you meant water flowing down from the top of the faucet into that hole.

Comment: Someone else installed the faucet, and there were leaks everywhere.  I lifted the faucet from the sink formed a seal around the underside of the base (there was none).  I was very careful and applied lots of sealant.  That stopped most of the leak.  Right now, I can see the water coming down the stopper rod, and I tested the leak point by first pouring water around the base of the faucet (no leak), then pouring water around the stopper rod (suddenly a leak).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by water travelling up the faucet because the faucet is entire assembly.  From what I could google, what to me is the "neck" is called a "spout".  Maybe we are using different terms?  I've modified the image to point out the spout/neck.

Comment: That is a hole in the casting I answered prior to reading comments, there is nothing below the hole if a o ring was on the rod it would have nothing to keep it in place very high end ones hav a screw on cap that has a nylon guide but even those are not water tight they look nicer and the nylon keeps the plunger from rubbing and scratching.  I agree with Ecnerwal +

Comment: Unless something highly unusual (that would be the actual problem here) has been cropped out of the picture on the left side, there's still no reason for water to be on the top side of the faucet where the hole is. Water should be coming out of the bottom side of the faucet, and heading into the sink. For the faucet to get water on top of itself requires some non-stock modification, or unusual hand-washing technique.

Comment: I modified the question to explain.

Comment: wrap a washcloth around the under cabinet assembly to catch runoff; it's hard to imagine a bucket being needed, and if it is, you're not using the sink correctly ;)

Comment: Thanks, but the cloth will just drip.  There's enough water for that.  But the container is just a tofu container, a but wider than a margarine tub (or actually, the same size as the larger tubs).  About 6" diameter.  I taped it into place after scribing an outline around the circumference for future reference.

Comment: that's a surprising amount of water, but i'll take your word. At least put a washcloth or natural sponge in the container to wick it out and curtail the need to sporadically empty it. you could also put a washcloth on the faucet while using to prevent ingress in the first place. I might consider pulling the stopper up all the way, rubbing soap on the metal stick, then squirting hotglue into the circular gap around the stick, pushing down on the rod when it half-cools, which should reduce the size of the opening and encourage some water to "overflow" the side, instead trickling down the hole.

Comment: even if a wrapped washcloth dripped, it would reduce the amount of built-up water needing dumped. i would also apply Rain-X on the faucet body all over the top, except for a half-inch margin around the hole. That should let the water take an easier path over the side, reducing the amount that makes it down the chute.

Comment: @dandavis: I appreciate the extra measures, but I'm going for simplicity.  A dripping cloth on the underside will probably grow mould or mildew.  I'll hold off on adding chemicals to the faucet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never seen a seal on the plunger that actuates the stopper

It is normally a hole that the shaft drops through then you attach another piece that clamps to the pivot rod from the plunger rod,

The plunger is not normally sealed.

The pivot rod is a short rod with a ball in the center, this has a seal

The pivot may capture the stopper and pull down or just push up and drop with gravity

Comment: OK, so it is normal for water travelling down the spout/neck (see image in posted question) and enter the stopper rod hole will leak down, and you have to put a bin there to catch it?  Before they installed this faucet, the old faucet neck hand a more rounded top, and water didn't have much chance to travel down the neck toward the stopper rod hole.

Comment: Frankly, that faucet is designed badly. There should be a little hump that the pull shaft can go through, so water can't get to the hole. You may need the bucket, yes. Or try to keep water from getting on top of the faucet.

Comment: I would say it is not normal for water to run on top of the spout, water comes out the bottom

Comment: @user2153235 As Ed notes, that hole is not sealed and indeed water flowing in will leak down under the sink. This is just an issue of a poorly-designed faucet (all too common these days as selling price is everything). As Triplefault writes, a properly-designed faucet will be shaped so dripped-on water does not flow toward and into the hole.

Comment: The previous faucet's neck had a cross section had a much more rounded top, so water rarely travelled down the length of the spout to the hole.  These faucets were replaced en masse throughout the high-rise,  I suspect that it was a decision based on style rather than borne from plumbing knowledge.  :(